# NSArray release crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Another puzzler. I have an NSArray (iTours) containing 3 Objects and a retain count of 1.

This Array is released in the object dealloc method as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"retain count für iTouren: %d", [iTours retainCount]);
    [iTours release];  // triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
    [super  dealloc];
}
```

The console window shows the following message (no further details):

> Program received signal: 
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

any clues what's going on? What did I miss?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely, you are over-releasing `iTouren` and, thus, that call to `release` is causing the crash.   That is, `iTouren` is already deallocated by the time you release the containing array and when that containing array sends `release` to the already deallocated `iTouren` your app crashes.

(Of course, `iTours` might be the object that is already deallocated.  In any case, it is an over-release problem.)

Turn on zombie detection and see if that barfs up the specific problem.

Note that the

### number returned by `retainCount` is useless

.  Absolute retain counts are an implementation detail and will often be a specific value that seems like nonsense.

In this case, the final `release` of an object does not decrement the retain count.  Why? Because that'd be a wasted cycle when the object is about to be deallocated anyway.  It would be impossible for `retainCount` to return 0 because, by definition, an object with a retain count of 0 has already been deallocated and, thus, is no longer a viable message receiver anyway.

Comment: Zombie confirmed the overrelease. Now I wonder why, since I declare and alloc the array in the init method. May be it's related to the object being a view that is pushed onto a navigation stack.  .... but this I first need to investigate ... will log a new question if I can't figure it out.

Thanks the good help !

Comment: With collection classes, also check that you haven't over-released any of the collected objects... suspect that release a collection will release all of the collected objects, which may cause a segfault at that point

Answer (score 4):

Never, ever, ever, rely on the retainCount method.

Ever.

Did I mention ever?

Answer (score 0):

One is `iTours` the other one `iTouren`. You are logging a different object than that being released.

Comment: iTours is an array that contains 3 objects, one of which is iTouren.  At least that is what the first line of the question implies.

Comment: sorry the confusion, it is iTours for both ... I misedited it ... now corrected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `iTours` and `iTouren` are different objects (namely that iTours is an `NSArray` containing `iTouren`), you've over-released `iTours`; maybe you had a failure in a setter and `iTours` was released without being reassigned and retained.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your array does not contains itself.  Releasing an array also release every object in it.  Of course, if this is the case, the array should have a release count of two before you release it because arrays retain their elements.

Answer (score 0):

A released and deallocated object will have a retain count of 1. A non-released object about to be released and deallocated will also have a retain count of 1. (Assuming memory is ever allocated for the object, some strings and numbers are never allocated, implementation detail that changes per Mac OS X release)

When an object is deallocated in current versions of Mac OS X, the memory is marked as free, nothing about the object is modified (unless you tell it to be). Thus, the retain count remains identical to the retain count before it was released.

This is the make a mistake and DIAF approach that help makes Mac OS X so solid.